# Upload file on admin page, when adding a new row to the database

Tags: django, django-admin

I am making a streaming app for my company, and I have a Model with the video title, a description, publication date, etc. And I want to make the people who are in charge of adding the videos to upload a 1080p version of the video, and then use `ffmpeg` to convert it to 720p, 480p, and other formats. Then, move those files to the filesystem.

How would you do this on the admin page?

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want to access the 1080p, 720p, and 480p versions directly from the model. For example, if the model had the fields:

```
video_1080 = VideoFile()
video_720  = VideoFile()
video_480  = VideoFile()
```

Then you could just override the save function of MyModel, the model in question:

```
def save(self):
    if self.video_1080:
        # Something like this. I don't know the syntax.
        self.video_720 = ffmpeg.convert(self.video_1080, 720)
        self.video_480 = ffmpeg.convert(self.video_1080, 480)

    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Is it possible to let people add files in the save page of django admin, if there is not a file column on the model?

Comment: Yes, people can add files if they are entered into the model as a FileField https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield. Edit: I may not understand what you're asking. To upload a file directly through Django, it has to be a FileField. You can always extend the FileField class to include other attributes if you need them. So instead of extending models.Model, you will extend models.FileField. This will give it all the information you need, as well as the information FileField needs to upload and manage files.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I thought `FileField` was used for database blobs.

Comment: FileField handles the upload and storage of a file, and then stores a reference to that file in the database, so it doesn't have to store the actual file with the object.